# Rxjava crash on android

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp, retrofit2

I m using the latest version of Rx java along with ok HTTP and retrofit .My app crashes randomly with this error

```
04-08 11:35:39.462 23977-24995/packageName.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x12 in tid 24995 (RxCachedThreadS)
```

No other log get's printed to the log cat.
I have unsubscribed all of my subscriptions.
I mostly used Rx for my network layer. This issue occurs in case I hit lots of web services in quick succession

I am having this issue on lollipop only, it works fine in marshmallow as well as on kitkat.
Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks alot in advance :)

Here is the complete stack till the crash occurred from start

```
04-08 12:16:53.050 858-2551/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.FiltersListActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:16:53.107 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:16:53.358 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.FiltersListActivity,wp,ca,288
04-08 12:16:53.358 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.FiltersListActivity: +288ms
04-08 12:16:53.760 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 34653(1901KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(240KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 36MB/38MB, paused 7.311ms total 71.167ms
04-08 12:16:56.327 858-874/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:16:56.386 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:16:56.547 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17486(844KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(111KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 37MB/38MB, paused 14.428ms total 89.228ms
04-08 12:16:56.661 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:16:56.740 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity,wp,ca,403
04-08 12:16:56.741 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity: +403ms
04-08 12:16:56.753 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:16:56.947 17300-17315/packageName.internal.dev W/art: Suspending all threads took: 55.759ms
04-08 12:16:57.019 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 43696(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 32(11MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 11.843ms total 143.929ms
04-08 12:16:59.151 858-2688/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:16:59.211 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:16:59.504 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity,wp,ca,340
04-08 12:16:59.504 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity: +340ms
04-08 12:17:03.746 858-2532/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.ProductDetailActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:03.794 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:04.209 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:04.219 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:04.304 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.ProductDetailActivity,wp,ca,543
04-08 12:17:04.304 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.ProductDetailActivity: +543ms
04-08 12:17:05.579 858-1932/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:05.640 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:05.829 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:05.903 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity,wp,ca,294
04-08 12:17:05.904 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity: +294ms
04-08 12:17:05.919 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:06.855 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
04-08 12:17:08.076 858-2690/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:08.151 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:08.209 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BidListFragment{1aa6b863 #0 id=0x7f0d0090 android:switcher:2131558544:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
04-08 12:17:08.297 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity,wp,ca,179
04-08 12:17:08.297 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity: +179ms
04-08 12:17:09.964 858-1324/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.OngoingBidDetailActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:10.027 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:10.292 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 260920(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 22(480KB) LOS objects, 21% free, 29MB/37MB, paused 6.178ms total 169.661ms
04-08 12:17:10.340 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.OngoingBidDetailActivity,wp,ca,340
04-08 12:17:10.340 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.OngoingBidDetailActivity: +340ms
04-08 12:17:11.706 858-1324/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4008000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:11.795 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:11.880 17300-17363/packageName.internal.dev I/PlayServicesUtils: GCM Registration Token: eH42MBumKOU:APA91bHjCES1yVIRp3NSqFdU-U6xHfL129wGUVR6sMfk4-iykom6vw11YGJAH9z6L8DwjMNAv8OnNYSCyi7M_6RUfiJxmYh5N0ywCizAAgzXgDjyARef9zIhOOBL3NTYiVGPs6UbCTlT
04-08 12:17:12.042 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:12.058 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity,wp,ca,304
04-08 12:17:12.059 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity: +304ms
04-08 12:17:12.937 17300-17315/packageName.internal.dev W/art: Suspending all threads took: 39.701ms
04-08 12:17:12.947 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 160986(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(165KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 30MB/37MB, paused 2.334ms total 134.457ms
04-08 12:17:17.609 858-1498/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:17.657 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:17.849 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:18.042 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity,wp,ca,417
04-08 12:17:18.042 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity: +417ms
04-08 12:17:20.281 858-1932/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:20.342 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:20.634 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity,wp,ca,339
04-08 12:17:20.635 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity: +339ms
04-08 12:17:23.042 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
04-08 12:17:23.964 17300-17315/packageName.internal.dev W/art: Suspending all threads took: 55.198ms
04-08 12:17:23.979 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 179189(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 32(1036KB) LOS objects, 37% free, 26MB/42MB, paused 3.113ms total 197.786ms
04-08 12:17:24.232 858-1324/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:24.318 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:24.368 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BidListFragment{3d0230b3 #0 id=0x7f0d0090 android:switcher:2131558544:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
04-08 12:17:24.456 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity,wp,ca,192
04-08 12:17:24.456 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity: +192ms
04-08 12:17:26.021 858-1498/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4008000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:26.117 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:26.202 17300-17366/packageName.internal.dev I/PlayServicesUtils: GCM Registration Token: eH42MBumKOU:APA91bHjCES1yVIRp3NSqFdU-U6xHfL129wGUVR6sMfk4-iykom6vw11YGJAH9z6L8DwjMNAv8OnNYSCyi7M_6RUfiJxmYh5N0ywCizAAgzXgDjyARef9zIhOOBL3NTYiVGPs6UbCTlT
04-08 12:17:26.381 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:26.405 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity,wp,ca,335
04-08 12:17:26.405 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity: +335ms
04-08 12:17:29.572 858-6993/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.ProductListActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:29.618 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:29.795 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:29.814 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.ProductListActivity,wp,ca,229
04-08 12:17:29.814 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.ProductListActivity: +229ms
04-08 12:17:30.401 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:31.261 858-2690/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:31.320 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:31.510 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:31.548 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity,wp,ca,277
04-08 12:17:31.548 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity: +277ms
04-08 12:17:31.555 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:32.858 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
04-08 12:17:33.903 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/StartBidPresenter: Token mismatched.
04-08 12:17:36.291 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
04-08 12:17:38.180 858-2439/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:38.274 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:38.327 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BidListFragment{3d69502f #0 id=0x7f0d0090 android:switcher:2131558544:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
04-08 12:17:38.434 17300-17315/packageName.internal.dev W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.627ms
04-08 12:17:38.448 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 271280(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 18(352KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 31MB/39MB, paused 2.165ms total 195.284ms
04-08 12:17:38.493 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity,wp,ca,289
04-08 12:17:38.493 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity: +289ms
04-08 12:17:41.031 858-2439/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4008000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:41.128 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:41.218 17300-17366/packageName.internal.dev I/PlayServicesUtils: GCM Registration Token: eH42MBumKOU:APA91bHjCES1yVIRp3NSqFdU-U6xHfL129wGUVR6sMfk4-iykom6vw11YGJAH9z6L8DwjMNAv8OnNYSCyi7M_6RUfiJxmYh5N0ywCizAAgzXgDjyARef9zIhOOBL3NTYiVGPs6UbCTlT
04-08 12:17:41.393 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:41.415 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity,wp,ca,332
04-08 12:17:41.415 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity: +332ms
04-08 12:17:42.436 858-2514/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:42.491 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:42.762 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:42.780 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 170957(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 6(100KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 33MB/39MB, paused 3.465ms total 121.605ms
04-08 12:17:42.964 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity,wp,ca,505
04-08 12:17:42.964 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity: +505ms
04-08 12:17:45.350 858-1932/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:45.413 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:45.725 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity,wp,ca,344
04-08 12:17:45.725 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity: +344ms
04-08 12:17:47.085 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
04-08 12:17:48.105 858-2690/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:48.204 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:48.259 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BidListFragment{26ce987 #0 id=0x7f0d0090 android:switcher:2131558544:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
04-08 12:17:48.386 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity,wp,ca,215
04-08 12:17:48.386 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity: +215ms
04-08 12:17:49.910 858-1498/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4008000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:50.064 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:50.206 17300-17363/packageName.internal.dev I/PlayServicesUtils: GCM Registration Token: eH42MBumKOU:APA91bHjCES1yVIRp3NSqFdU-U6xHfL129wGUVR6sMfk4-iykom6vw11YGJAH9z6L8DwjMNAv8OnNYSCyi7M_6RUfiJxmYh5N0ywCizAAgzXgDjyARef9zIhOOBL3NTYiVGPs6UbCTlT
04-08 12:17:50.213 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 214387(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 44(1575KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 27MB/43MB, paused 3.144ms total 184.413ms
04-08 12:17:50.433 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:50.448 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity,wp,ca,446
04-08 12:17:50.448 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity: +446ms
04-08 12:17:51.316 858-2551/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:51.383 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:51.608 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:51.760 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity,wp,ca,406
04-08 12:17:51.760 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity: +406ms
04-08 12:17:54.020 858-1324/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:54.113 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:54.400 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity,wp,ca,318
04-08 12:17:54.400 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity: +318ms
04-08 12:17:55.352 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
04-08 12:17:56.409 858-2551/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:56.500 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:56.545 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BidListFragment{2467eaa6 #0 id=0x7f0d0090 android:switcher:2131558544:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
04-08 12:17:56.650 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity,wp,ca,215
04-08 12:17:56.650 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.fragment.MyBidsActivity: +215ms
04-08 12:17:58.092 858-1397/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4008000 cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:58.266 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:58.351 17300-17363/packageName.internal.dev I/PlayServicesUtils: GCM Registration Token: eH42MBumKOU:APA91bHjCES1yVIRp3NSqFdU-U6xHfL129wGUVR6sMfk4-iykom6vw11YGJAH9z6L8DwjMNAv8OnNYSCyi7M_6RUfiJxmYh5N0ywCizAAgzXgDjyARef9zIhOOBL3NTYiVGPs6UbCTlT
04-08 12:17:58.585 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000348374194
04-08 12:17:58.605 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity,wp,ca,404
04-08 12:17:58.606 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity: +404ms
04-08 12:17:59.278 17300-17320/packageName.internal.dev I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 337068(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(209KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 32MB/40MB, paused 2.244ms total 180.826ms
04-08 12:17:59.459 858-2690/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:17:59.502 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:17:59.725 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-08 12:17:59.905 858-907/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity,wp,ca,435
04-08 12:17:59.905 858-907/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity: +435ms
04-08 12:18:01.888 858-2551/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity (has extras)} from uid 10668 on display 0
04-08 12:18:01.946 17300-17300/packageName.internal.dev I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-08 12:18:02.134 17300-17366/packageName.internal.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x12 in tid 17366 (RxCachedThreadS)
04-08 12:18:02.193 271-271/? I/DEBUG: pid: 17300, tid: 17366, name: RxCachedThreadS  >>> packageName.internal.dev <<<
04-08 12:18:03.781 858-21677/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity
04-08 12:18:03.790 858-21677/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 2 packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity
04-08 12:18:03.823 858-1932/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{829a5f5 u0 packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.StartBiddingActivity}
04-08 12:18:03.827 858-2514/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{37fa287a u0 packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.BidListActivity}
04-08 12:18:03.831 858-2551/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{1a259e3c u0 packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity}
04-08 12:18:03.903 858-1952/? I/ActivityManager: Process packageName.internal.dev (pid 17300) has died
04-08 12:18:03.939 858-1952/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 21684:packageName.internal.dev/u0a668 for activity packageName.internal.dev/packageName.ui.activity.MainActivity
04-08 12:18:04.146 21684-21684/packageName.internal.dev I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
```

Comment: What you show us? One crash line with problem in point memory? Can you provide crash logS.

Comment: Are you using the Android NDK? Because the message "SIGSEGV" comes usually from a the NDK.

Comment: Nope basically i resolved this by providing  a custom executor to the rx

Comment: @VardaanSharma can you tell em how you solve this?

Comment: Upgrading to newer version of Rx Java and ok HTTP resolved this bug for me

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?